# Add OpenLayers3 controls to qgis2web project

Tags: qgis, openlayers, qgis2web

I am trying to get some of the control sets offered by OpenLayers into a project exported using [QGIS2WEB](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2web/). I am looking to use the export to Pdf [function](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html) and have successfully created a test page using it. However I do not know how to integrate the function/script into the qgis2web project. Eventually I would also like to also add the [draw feature](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-features.html) control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you place your extra code in the output file `resources/qgis2web.js`. That is the file where `ol.Map` is instantiated. You should therefore be able to match that up with the example page you cite.