# Drawing new features with QGIS2web plugin

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, javascript, openlayers, qgis2web

I would like to draw shapes with QGIS2web plugin

According to the query here:

[Add OpenLayers3 controls to qgis2web project](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268736/add-openlayers3-controls-to-qgis2web-project)

I should be able to develop the qgis2web.js file further behind the `ol.Map` section.

I found a good drawing shapes test for Openlayers here:

https://cdn.rawgit.com/HamHamFonFon/ol3-drawFeatures/82f29a3f/examples/basic_use.html

from where I picked up the relevant files. I did the following steps:

1. Linked the essential scripts and csses into my index.html page:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Added, and next linked the following script and css files:

   ```
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/ol3-drawcontrols.css">
       <script src="resources/ol3-controldrawfeatures.js"></script>
   ```
3. Placed the following section:

   ```
     var vector_draw = new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: new ol.source.Vector(),
   style: new ol.style.Style({
       fill: new ol.style.Fill({
           color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
       }),
       stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
           color: '#ffcc33',
           width: 2
       }),
       image: new ol.style.Circle({
           radius: 7,
           fill: new ol.style.Fill({
               color: '#ffcc33'
           })
       })
   })
    });
   ```

in the **layers.js** file

4. Situated another section:

   ```
       var options = {
      "style_buttons" : null, /** @var {string} glyphicon|default */
      "draw": {
       "Point": true,
       "LineString": true,
       "Square": true,
       "Circle": true,
       "Polygon": true
   }
    };
   ```

before the

```
    var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({tipLabel: "Layers"});
```

in the qgis2web.js file

1. At the finish I placed the following line:

   ```
    var buttonsDrawControls = new ol.control.ControlDrawFeatures({vector_draw, options});
    map.addControl(buttonsDrawControls);
   ```

but the map is gone.

The console says:

**Uncaught TypeError: ol.inherits is not a function
at ol3-controldrawfeatures.js:209
at ol3-controldrawfeatures.js:16
at ol3-controldrawfeatures.js:18**

which refers to:

at ol3-controldrawfeatures.js 209 `ol.inherits(ol.control.ControlDrawFeatures, ol.control.Control);`
at ol3-controldrawfeatures.js:16   `root.ControlDrawFeatures = factory(root.ol);`
at ol3-controldrawfeatures.js:18   `}(this, function(ol) {`

The similar problem was raised here:

[ol.inherits in OpenLayers 6](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324606/ol-inherits-in-openlayers-6)

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Ending' of undefined
at new ol.control.ControlDrawFeatures (ol3-controldrawfeatures.js:24)
at qgis2web.js:135**

which refers to:

at ol3-controldrawfeatures      `options.draw.Ending = true;`

at qgis2web.js        `var buttonsDrawControls = new ol.control.ControlDrawFeatures({vector_draw, options});`

UPDATE:

After expanding the `draw.on('drawend'`, function

```
 draw.on('drawend',
  function(evt) {
    measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
    measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
    // unset sketch
    sketch = null;
    // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
    measureTooltipElement = null;
    createMeasureTooltip();
    ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
  }, this);
 var value = typeSelect.value;
    if (value === 'None'){
    } else {
        var geometryFunction;
        if(value !== 'None' && value !== 'Square' && value !== 'Box') {
            console.log(value)
            draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                source: sourcedraw,
                type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (typeSelect.value)
            });
        } else if(value === 'Square'){
            console.log(value)
            value = 'Circle';
            geometryFunction = ol.interaction.Draw.createRegularPolygon(4);
            draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                source: sourcedraw,
                type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (value),
                geometryFunction: geometryFunction
            });
        } else if(value === 'Box'){
            console.log(value)
            value = 'Circle';
            geometryFunction = ol.interaction.Draw.createBox();
            draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                source: sourcedraw,
                type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (value),
                geometryFunction: geometryFunction
            });
        };
        map.addInteraction(draw)
     };
```

I still get an error:

**Uncaught TypeError: ol.inherits is not a function
at ol3-controldrawfeatures.js:209
at ol3-controldrawfeatures.js:16
at ol3-controldrawfeatures.js:18**

The full code to my map is available [here](https://sitec-is-survey.site/maps/index.html)

What have I done wrong?

**IInd approach**

I used another code, which seems to be even better than the first one. Basically i am able to draw all the features except of the rectangle.

where after the selection my cursour is sticked to the map dragging it unless I leave the map canvas completely.

After implementation to my JavaScript file, which you can find below:

https://jsfiddle.net/t0dnpL73/

I am getting an error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getGeometry')
at e.modifyDrawing_ (Draw.js:688)
at e.handlePointerMove_ (Draw.js:590)
at e.handleEvent (Draw.js:495)
at e.handleMapBrowserEvent (PluggableMap.js:846)
at e.dispatchEvent (Target.js:115)
at e.relayEvent_ (MapBrowserEventHandler.js:230)**

referring me to the `draw.js` file, which i can find anywhere in my Qgis2web map repositories.

The issue is very similar to this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52848282/drawing-and-modifying-vector-features-openlayers

[image]

how can I fix this problem? Is there something I could change easily? I tried to change

```
var rectangleInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
type: 'LineString',
```

to `type: 'Polygon'`   but it's still the same.

Comment: Without seeing the complete code as it is (not only isolated excerpts), it all would be just guessing. Any errors in the browser debugger console?

Comment: @TomazicM you are right. I should have to see the console. I did it now. My query has been updated.

Comment: It looks like the OL version you are using is not the right one for ol3-controldrawfeatures.js you are trying to use. Try replacing your current version of OL with version the example above is using: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.14.0/ol.css and https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.14.0/ol.js

Comment: And you should put `<script src="./resources/ol3-controldrawfeatures.js"></script>` before `<script src="./resources/qgis2web.js"></script>`.

Comment: @TomazicM could you explain to me why in the 2nd example I constantly get the error cannot read properties or null? I have completely no idea how to fix it.

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. I have no console error anymore, but there is no reaction at all.

Answer (score 1):

The deprecated `ol.inherits` method is easy to add back

```
<script src="./resources/ol.js"></script>
<script>
  ol.inherits = function(child,parent) {
    child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
  }
</script>
```

But there is no guarantee that old third party add-ons will work with later versions of OpenLayers than they were designed for as there have been many other changes between version 3 and 6.

Comment: OK, thank you. I will check tomorrow. However, I shouldn't worry about the changes between OpenLayers 3 and 6. The QGIS2Web plugin still works at 3.0 I guess, as all the files are dated back to Oct 2020.

Comment: Unnfortunatey it doesn't work. Instead of it I am getting error:
ol3-controldrawfeatures.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND